# Python client hazhalcast fail to connect HazelcastClient.ClusterService

Tags: python, client, hazelcast

Using ref example 
https://hazelcast.com/blog/getting-started-python-client/
we are not able to run cluster node

May 13, 2019 05:25:03 PM HazelcastClient.ClusterService
WARNING: [3.12] [dev] [hz.client_0] Unable to get alive cluster connection, attempt 2 of 2
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Did you start the server?

Comment: Which server -hazelcast cluster server ??

Comment: Does python dont have option to start hazelcast cluster instance server???       https://hazelcast.com/blog/hazelcast-python-client-3-9-introducing-the-python-3-support/

Comment: No, you need to start the hazelcast-cluster separately. Did you read this section?: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-python-client#12-working-with-hazelcast-imdg-clusters